# Row wise conditional formatting in power bi matrix Visual

Tags: powerbi, dax, conditional-formatting

[Matrix Visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62YbG.png)Hi I want to create a dax query for a case that if there is a value in a matrix visual and if there is a value greater than or equal to 200 in any cell I want to **highlight whole row ** as red else I want if the value is less that 200 then green in that **particular specific cell**.

I am expecting a DAX query for conditional formatting.

Answer (score 0):

**Steps**

1. You will need two new Measures:

```
Matrix Sales = COALESCE(SUM('Order'[Sales]), "")


Matrix RowCell Formatting =
  var vCell = SUM('Order'[Sales])
  var vRow = CALCULATE(SUM('Order'[Sales]), ALLEXCEPT('Order', 'Order'[Order ID]) )
  RETURN SWITCH(TRUE(), vRow >= 200, "Row", vCell < 200 && NOT(ISBLANK(vCell)), "Cell")
```

2. Update your Matrix to use `Matrix Sales` for the `Values`.
3. Set-up Conditional Formatting like so:
    
   [image]

---

**Notes**

- To highlight a row (or every cell in a row), each cell must have a value. Hence why `Matrix Sales` returns the sum sales or an empty string.
- It is not possible to add Conditional Formatting to the row headers.

---

**Result**
[image]